# Uncheck a checkbox after multiple checkbox are being checked

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need help unchecking a checkbox that is being selected on clicking the checkbox again. Right now multiple checkboxes are being selected and their checkedItems are being returned to the parent component. But the returned checkedItems does not contain the value of the last checked checkbox.
Here is my piece of code :

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function Checkbox({ form, handleReturn, data }) {
  const [checkedItems, setCheckedItems] = useState({});

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setCheckedItems({
      ...checkedItems,
      [event.target.id]: event.target.id,
    });
    handleReturn(Object.keys(checkedItems));
  };

  return (
    <div className="p-3 ">
      <h3 className="text-white text-shadow mt-4">{form.label}</h3>
      <h6 className="text-white text-shadow mt-4">{form.description}</h6>
      <div
        className="row px-4 text-white text-shadow mt-4">
        {form.options && form.options.length > 0
          ? form.options.map((item, index) => (
              <div className="form-check offset-md-1 col-md-10 mb-6">
                <div class="btn-block ">
                  <input
                    checked={checkedItems[item.id]}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    type="checkbox"
                    // checked={input === item.id ? "checked" : ""}
                    required={form.mandatoryField === true ? "required" : ""}
                    name={item.name}
                    id={item.id}
                    className="form-check-input "
                  ></input>
                  <label class="form-check-label px-1" for={item.name}>
                    {item.name}
                  </label>
                </div>
              </div>
            ))
          : ""}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
export default Checkbox;
```